# Angular 9 error on Build : Cannot find name WriteStream & ReadStream

Tags: angular

Since my update to Angular 9, I can't build my app. `ng serve` works perfectly. It seems to be an error with typescript but I don't understand it.

Can you help me ?

Error on build :

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:838:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WriteStream'.
838         stdout: WriteStream;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:842:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WriteStream'.
842         stderr: WriteStream;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:843:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadStream'.
843         stdin: ReadStream;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~
```

My Angular Config :

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 12.16.2
OS: linux x64

Angular: 9.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.1
@angular/cli                      9.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.1
@schematics/angular               9.1.1
@schematics/update                0.901.1
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Comment: Could you also show us your package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read my last commits and I saw something very interesting !

I set up the release tracking with Sentry (https://docs.sentry.io/workflow/releases/?platform=javascript) with an autofetching of the npm version

> release : process.env.npm_package_version

and my IDE (Webstorm) automatically add a line in my tsconfig.app.json.

```
  "files": [
    ...,
    "../node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts"
```

Without the line it works well but I have to write the version manually !